# How to add values in the stack together

Tags: assembly, avr

Basically what the question states. In AVR 8-bit Assembly, I need to add *x* amount of values on top of the register together and then store them in a register pair. How would I go about this?

Comment: What you mean *top of the register*?

Comment: If you mean "top of the **stack**", then copy the stack pointer to X or Y, and loop over that array, loading and adding, with `adc r, 0` for the high half.

Comment: right yes, top of stack. I was hella tired and burnt out when I wrote this.

Comment: Pop the top two values into two registers, one being the accumulator. Add the second register to the accumulator. Then continue popping the stack into the second register and adding that to the accumulator `x` amount of times.